# Running Code First Migrations manually through migrate.exe

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-migrations

I am currently trying to get my migrations running through command line using the migrate.exe tool.

My project structure is as follows:

> MyProject.WebAPI - my API project which accesses method in
>   Repositories
>
> MyProject.Repositories - project responsible for all DB work,
>   including where the migration files are stored, context is configured, and Configuration class is held

Migrations work fine when running the WebAPI project as the DB initializer is set up there in the Application_Start as follows:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyProject.Repositories.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

The reason for wanting to not do this anymore, is for when I am installing the code to a machine.  I am aiming to get the database initialized at install time, so need to be able to run migrations from command line.   To start to do this, I have got a copy of `migrate.exe` in the bin directory of the WebApi project, as well as the `MyProject.Repositories.dll`.

I want to therefore be able to use the web.config file in the WebApi project to configure up and run the initializer.  The entity framework portion of this looks as follows:

```
<configuration>
  ....

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
      <contexts>
          <context type="Repositories.MyContext, MyProject.Repositories">
              <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Repositories.MyContext, MyProject.Repositories], [Repositories.Configuration, MyProject.Repositories]], EntityFramework">
              </databaseInitializer>
          </context>
      </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And I am running migrate.exe as follows:

```
migrate.exe MyProject.Repositories.dll /startUpDirectory:"%current%" /connectionStringName:MyConnecitonString /startUpConfigurationFile:"%parent%\web.config"
```

current and parent are just variables set in a batch file.

When this set up is run, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to set database initializer of type 'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[MyProject.CampaignManagerContext, MyProject.Repositories],     [Repositories.Configuration, MyProject.Repositories]], EntityFramework' 

for DbContext type 'Repositories.MyContext, MyProject.Repositories' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.
```

Is this possible to do between two projects, or would I have to run this on the actual Repositories project itself, using its own app.config?

EDIT:
I have been working more on this, and have changed my call to migrate to just:

```
migrate.exe MyProject.Repositories.dll /connectionString:MyConnectionString /connectionProviderName:System.Data.SqlClient
```

This gives me an error of:

```
ERROR: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

Looks like it is getting closer to working...

Comment: What's the inner exception?

Comment: I wish I knew, not found any way of seeing it

Comment: Have you tried it without the `/startUpConfigurationFile` option? I thought migrate to latest was the default.

Comment: @Stefan if I remove that I get `ERROR: No connection string named 'MyContext' could be found in the application config file.`

Comment: you can explicit set the connectionstring with `/connectionString`.

Comment: More details about the migration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx

Comment: Or otherwise build an exe that query's a single row in the database. If you've set the DB Initializer first it will practically do the same thing :)

Comment: @Stefan even changing the migrate flags to only have `/connectionString` I get the no connection string error...

Comment: ... :|  that leaves me blank. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Stefan, I know this is 2 years too late, but I just discovered that if you use the /verbose flag, it will display the inner exception.